# Error libreria con maven. Sin error con la misma librería externa

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite, spire

Estoy intentando utilizar la libreria spire.office.free para gestionar ficheros de office desde java. Para ello tengo un proyecto usando spring tool suite con maven para la descarga de esa librería.
El problema es que al ejecutar el código obtengo el siguiente error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh (in unnamed module @0x29647f75) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x29647f75
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.spr??(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.spr??(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprfqg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprhqg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.xls.core.spreadsheet.XlsWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.xls.Workbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Eu.Extrae.Principal.main(Principal.java:21)
```

A la vez la consola de java me informa de que no es capaz de acceder al código de la librería

[image: Class file editor]

Lo curioso del asunto es que si descargo la spire.office.free y la uso como librería externa el problema desaparece y todo funciona correctamente.
Sé que eso es una solución al problema pero yo prefiero utilizar maven en cualquier caso

¿Alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Estás agregando a tu pom la [última versión](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/e-iceblue/spire.office.free/5.3.1) que está en Maven?  ¿Que versión de la librería y de java usas? ¿Probaste siguiendo su [guía para maven](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Licensing/How-to-install-Spire.PDF-for-Java-from-Maven-Repository.html) (suponiendo pagas licencia)? ¿Usas la versión free o pagas?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Uso código de ejemplo. El pom tan sólo está implementado para poder añadir el repositorio oficial y las dependencias. Uso la librería gratuita
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.e-iceblue</id>
            <name>e-iceblue</name>
            <url>https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
 </repositories> 
 <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>e-iceblue</groupId>
         <artifactId>spire.office.free</artifactId>
         <version>5.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>

Answer (score 0):

Solución al problema.
Al final monté un repositorio local en el directorio .m2 de mi equipo e instalé en él la librería que me generaba el problema. Una vez hecho esto el problema se resolvió.